# Crashlytics iOS - Crash at line 0 - Swift sources

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crashlytics

I'm currently facing a problem with some Swift source files when a crash occurs. Indeed, on Crashlytics I have a weird info about the line and the reason of the crash. It tells me the source has crashed at the **line 0** and it gives me a **SIGTRAP** error. I read that this error occurs when a Thread hits a BreakPoint. But the problem is that this error occurs while I'm not debugging (application test from TestFlight).

Here is an example when Crashlytics tells me there's a **SIGTRAP Error at line 0** :

```
// Method that crashs  
private func extractSubDataFrom(writeBuffer: inout Data, chunkSize: Int) -> Data? {  

        guard chunkSize > 0 else { // Prevent from having a 0 division  
            return nil  
        }  

        // Get nb of chunks to write (then the number of bytes from it)  
        let nbOfChunksToWrite: Int = Int(floor(Double(writeBuffer.count) / Double(chunkSize)))  
        let dataCountToWrite = max(0, nbOfChunksToWrite * chunkSize)  
        guard dataCountToWrite > 0 else {  
            return nil // Not enough data to write for now  
        }  

        // Extract data  
        let subData = writeBuffer.extractSubDataWith(range: 0..<dataCountToWrite)  
        return subData    
}
```

Another Swift file to explain what happens at the line "writeBuffer.extractSubDataWith(range: 0..

```
public extension Data {  

    //MARK: - Public  
    public mutating func extractSubDataWith(range: Range) -> Data? {  

        guard range.lowerBound >= 0 && range.upperBound <= self.count else {  
            return nil  
        }  

        // Get a copy of data and remove them from self  
        let subData = self.subdata(in: range)  
        self.removeSubrange(range)  

        return subData  
    }  
}
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong ? Or what can occurs this weird SIGTRAP error ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Crashing with a line of zero is indeed weird. But, common in Swift code.

The Swift compiler can do code generation on your behalf. This can happen quite a bit with generic functions, but may also happen for other reasons. When the compiler generates code, it also produces debug information for the code it generates. This debug information typically references the file that caused the code to be generated. But, the compiler tags it all with a line of `0` to distinguish it from code that was actually written by the developer.

These generic functions also do not have to be written by you - I've seen this happen with standard library functions too.

(Aside: I believe that the DWARF standard can, in fact, describe this situation more precisely. But, unfortunately Apple doesn't seem to use it in that way.)

Apple verified this line zero behavior via a Radar I filed about it a number of years ago. You can also poke around in your app's own debug data (via, for example dwarfdump) if you want to confirm.

One reason you might want to try to do this, is if you really don't trust that Crashlytics is labelling the lines correctly. There's a lot of stuff between their UI and the raw crash data. It is conceivable something's gone wrong. The only way you can confirm this is to grab the crashing address + binary, and do the lookup yourself. If dwarfdump tells you this happened at line zero, then that confirms this is just an artifact of compile-time code generation.

However, I would tend to believe there's nothing wrong with the Crashlytics UI. I just wanted to point it out as a possibility.

As for SIGTRAP - there's nothing weird about that at all. This is just an indication that the code being run has decided to terminate the process. This is different, for example, from a SIGBUS, where the OS does the terminating. This could be caused by Swift integer and/or range bounds checking. Your code does have some of that kind of thing in both places. And, since that would be so performance-critical - would be a prime candidate for inline code generation.

**Update**

It now seems like, at least in some situations, the compiler also now uses a file name of `<compiler-generated>`. I'm sure they did this to make this case clearer. So, it could be that with more recent versions of Swift, you'll instead see `<compiler-generated>:0`. This might not help tracking down a crash, but will least make things more obvious.

Comment: What is the suggested solution?

Comment: There really is no solution. This is something Swift does, and you have to be aware of it. I don't believe there is anything you can do to prevent the compiler from emitting this information.

Comment: Thank you @Mattie for this fine explanation of the issue. But how to debug the crash?