# Firebase crashlytics reports many <compiler-generated> line 0 crashes in my production build, are these crashes for real?

Tags: ios, swift, crash, firebase-crash-reporting

I am using websocket in my swift project and from last couple of weeks I am receiving these kind of crashes:

> < compiler-generated > line 0

```
Crashed: com.MyProject.Channel
0  MYProject                         0x100e53f7c specialized    Arrayat(_:) (<compiler-generated>)
1  MYProject                         0x100e55a3c   $S6MYProject7ChannelC20checkResponseMessage33_12B1408E1049A8D244FCDCBD3CEC  8679LL08responseE0yAA0bE0C_tFyyXEfU_ (Channel.swift:137)
2  MYProject                         0x100ce3de8 $SIg_Ieg_TR (<compiler-generated>)
3  MYProject                         0x100ce3e08 $SIeg_IyB_TR (<compiler-generated>)
```

More information from code :

```
Channel.TMLock.sync {
        var idx = 0
        for msg in Channel.trackedMsgs {
            mt = msg
            if msg.isResponseTo(responseMessage: responseMessage) {
                Channel.trackedMsgs.remove(at: idx)
                break
            }

            idx += 0
        }
    }

Channel.swift:137 => Channel.trackedMsgs.remove(at: idx)
```

Does anyone have any idea about this ?

Comment: If you attach code of method which includes Channel.swift:137 line, we may assume whats wrong.

Comment: @NazarLisovyi I added more code for better understanding.

Comment: Obviously, you want to remove the element with the index which is out of bounds. This logic looks wrong

Comment: @NazarLisovyi I also assumed same reason but I just don't understand the connection with (<compiler-generated>) connection.

Comment: Yes, `line 0` is a real thing in Swift stacktraces. Checkout the details in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872700/crashlytics-ios-crash-at-line-0-swift-sources.

Answer (score 2):

```
Channel.TMLock.sync {
    var idx = 0
    for msg in Channel.trackedMsgs {
        mt = msg
        if msg.isResponseTo(responseMessage: responseMessage) {
            Channel.trackedMsgs.remove(at: idx) -> Removing elements while iteration will cause crash
            break
        }

        idx += 0
    }
}
```

you can rewrite this as :

```
Channel.TMLock.sync {
        var idx = 0
        var indexOfElement = 0
        while indexOfElement < Channel.trackedMsgs.length{
        mt = msg
        if msg.isResponseTo(responseMessage: responseMessage) {
                Channel.trackedMsgs.remove(at: idx)
                break
            }

            idx += 0
            indexOfElement += 1
        }
    }
```